# How to let the user disable push notifications during certain hours with Ionic?

Tags: ionic3, firebase-cloud-messaging, cordova-plugin-fcm

I am developing an Android/iOS app using Ionic and I am sending push notifications from an other server using Firebase Cloud Messaging. I want to let the user specify during which hours they want to receive notifications. But as I understand it, FCM sends push notifications if the app is not open and it sends the message directly to the app for handling if it is open. This gives me little control over when to receive push notifications. I could maybe subscribe/unsubscribe to the topic somehow, but then I would need to have some kind of scheduled task.

What is a good way for solving this?